# Problema ao baixar codigo fonte appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

Quando escrevo o comando no cmd:

```
appcfg.py -A [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] -V [YOUR_VERSION_ID] download_app [OUTPUT_DIR]
```

Invés dele iniciar o download do código fonte, ele abre o arquivo appcfg.py que está no diretório.

Agora tentei escrever pelo powershell o mesmo comando, e invés de iniciar o download do codigo fonte, ele abriu o arquivo appcfg.py e começou a mostrar isso no prompt:

```
[main 2019-03-19T19:12:36.901Z] update#setState idle
[main 2019-03-19T19:13:06.902Z] update#setState checking for updates
[main 2019-03-19T19:13:07.107Z] update#setState idle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É so adicionar **python** antes do comando:

```
python appcfg.py -A [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] -V [YOUR_VERSION_ID] download_app [OUTPUT_DIR]
```